# Accidentialy getting items of an observable list in reverse order

Tags: c#, data-binding, binding, observablecollection

I am using a custom observable collection class (credits go to Dean Chalke: http://www.deanchalk.me.uk/post/Thread-Safe-Dispatcher-Safe-Observable-Collection-for-WPF.aspx) in order to modify a data-bound collection from a thread other that the UI thread.

This custom observable collection implements IList<> and INotifyCollectionChanged and contains a collection of type IList<> which stores all the elements of the actual (surrounding) observable collection.

When I data bind this custom observable collection to a WPF List the items of the observable list are getting displayed correctly except the fact that they are in reverse order !

A look into my code during runtime offers that the items of the embedded collection of type IList<> which resides inside the custom observable collection have the correct order. But when I look at the custom observable list it has the items in reverse order.

Maybe I should post some code to make this more clear :)

This is the custom observable collection:

```
public class ThreadSaveObservableCollection <T> : IList<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged {

     private IList<T> collection;

     public ThreadSaveObservableCollection () {

         collection = new List<T>();
     }

     ...

     public void Insert (int index, T item) {

        if (Thread.CurrentThread == uiDispatcher.Thread) {

            insert_(index, item);
        } else {

            uiDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action<int, T>(insert_), DispatcherPriority.Normal, new object[] {index, item});
        }
    }

    private void insert_ (int index, T item) {

        rwLock.AcquireWriterLock(Timeout.Infinite);

        collection.Insert(index, item);
        CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item));

        rwLock.ReleaseWriterLock();
    }

    ...
}
```

This is where I use the collection in the ViewModel:

```
...
public ThreadSaveCollection Log {get; set;}

public ViewModel () {

    Log = new ThreadSaveCollection();
}
...

public void Insert() {

     log.Instert(0, "entry1");
}
```

I create the binding between the object log and the WPF control dynamically:

```
LogList.ItemSource = ViewModel.Log;
```

Except this wrong-order issue everything seems to work quite fine: The threads do what they should do and the WPF list gets updated in time.

Again when stepping into the code the Log object of the ViewModel shows me the inverse order whereas the collection object inside the ThreadSaveObservableCollection has the items in the correct order.

I would really appreciate any help!
Thank you in advance ...

**UPDATE:** The statement log.Instert(0, "entry1"); is intentional since I want to have a list that is getting items over time and every new item should be inserted at the beginning of the list. In other words the newest item is always on top of the list. Nevertheless in my code the embedded collection has the desired order whereas the surrounding collection doesn't.

Why should there be a difference in the order of items anyway ?

**UPDATE:** Interestingly when I use Add() instead of insert the order is not getting reversed from the outside collection.

In other words: Regardless of whether I use Add(item) or Insert(0, item) I am always getting the same order of items in my ThreadSaveObservableCollection object of my ViewModel whereas the contained collection inside has the correct order.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to always be inserting new records at index 0

```
log.Inster(0, "entry1");
```

creating a first-in, first-out scenario.

If you insert

A
B
C

you will get back

C B A

Comment: Try using this collection without data binding, e.g. in a unit test, and see if you get the same result.

Comment: Ok, I have done that: When I am using the class without binding the collection does exactly what it should. So it seems the incorrect order resides only in the WPF control and is propagated through binding somehow ?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `Insert(0, "entry1")` you're putting the new value at the beginning of the list, which is why the order is reversed. You could use the Add method instead.

Answer (score 0):

To get a correct order in your WPF component, you can use a SortDescription:

```
yourListView.Items.SortDescriptions.Add( new SortDescription( "yourSourcePropertyToOrderBy", ListSortDirection.Ascending ) );
```

You can setup SortDescription in your gui-management oder directly in code behind of your WPF.